# Topology and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, reference-request

I'm curious about if there is some interesting research or books about finite topological spaces and combinatorics.

It should answer questions like

- How many topologial spaces with $n$ elements and a given property are there?
- Do there exist interesting properties exclusive for finite topological spaces? (Just like Lagrange or Sylow theorems in finite groups theory, for example).
- Can be those finite topological spaces and/or continuous functions between them classified or represented?

I have found only [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/stong2.pdf).

Comment: I have some unpublished results about finite topology spaces.  Those spaces are Alexandroff spaces.

Comment: A finite topological space amounts to a pre-ordered set, that is, a set with a specified reflexive, transitive relation on it. In one direction, given a topology on a set$X$, define the relation $x\leq y$ to mean that $x$ is in theclosure of $\{y\}$. In the other direction, given a pre-order on $X$, topologize $X$ by calling a subset $A$ open iff it is upward-closed, i.e., if $x\leq y$ and $x\in A$ then $y\in A$. It's easy to check that these two constructions are inverse to each other. The pre-order is a partial order iff the topology is $T_0$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space

Answer (score 0):

Try "Algebraic topology of finite topological spaces and its applications":

https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/barmak2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwis9dPQqYXaAhVGlpAKHfSgBdYQFjAHegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw0AfxT5__nz5W6x1o6aUIZX

I think the fist question you mention is still open, though.